# how to check stored value using android shared preferences

Tags: android, if-statement, onclick, sharedpreferences

How to avoid asking login every time using shared preferences , when users opens app. What I have tried is below to save value

```
mainbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sf = getSharedPreferences("userInput", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                final String i = sf.getString("FirstInput", "");
                if (et1.getText().toString().trim().length()>0 && et1.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(i)) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewOne.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
        
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            strInput1 = et1.getText().toString();
            if (strInput1.equals("string")) {
                SharedPreferences sf = getSharedPreferences("userInput", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();
                editor.putString("FirstInput", et1.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your input is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your input is not matching", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: please make sure the question clear..

Comment: After login Activity , this Activity is going on and in this I have one text box , one save button and this button "btn1" but after exit its not working again ask user input...

Comment: Actually its working fine but exit from Application its again asking to give user input why?

Comment: Is it not working cause for only extends Activity as like or getApplicationContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
when user login successful at that time you can save login status

SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
 editor.commit(); 

 after when user comes the app, at time
 boolean isAlreayLogin= settings.getBoolean("isLonin",false);

 if(isAlreayLogin)
  //then you have to start login activity manually without any input
```

Comment: I am doing as like but unfortunately app has topped mean its not working properly...where i have to put plz code in detail and give info to see above reference...

Comment: Your code is not in proper way would u like to modify?

Comment: When i am applying if(isAlreadyLogin) {} then ctx.getSharedPreference is not working and error is displaying as like it is redundant

Comment: if its possible then show your .java file i will be made changes on that

Answer (score 0):

```
if (et1.getText.toString.trim()!=null && et1.getText().toString().trim().length()>0 && et1.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(i))
```

please also check null condition

Comment: sorry put the et1.getText().tostring

Answer (score 0):

That code only works when you push the button. So, if you close the app and reopen again, it won't do anything but show the form again.

I think mayne you need to implement same code in onCreate or in onResume:

1. get last user logged in
2. get sharedPrefs and check user
3. if the user is OK -> open intent
4. else  if the user is WRONG -> show login form (don't do anything)

Comment: I am doing as like onResume but its not working properly

Comment: Could you re-explain your problem with the new changes? Is the only way we can help you.